# How to show user comments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I show all comments in the post#show?
comments_controller

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   def create
       @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment.user_id = current_user.id
       @comment.username = current_user.username
       @comment.post_id=@post.id
       @comment.save
       redirect_to post_path(@post)
   end
   def show
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
   end
   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :username)
   end
end
```

Models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user 
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post
end
```

the views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<ul class="img-list-single">
<li>
<a>
  <img src=<%= @post.url %>/>
  <span class="text-content"><span><%=@post.title%></span></span>
</a>
<%= @comment.username%>
<%if current_user%>
  <%= form_for :comment, :url => post_comments_path(@post) do |f|%>
      <%= f.text_field :text %>
      <%= f.submit%>
  <% end %>
  <%if current_user.id==@post.user_id%>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete, :onclick => " returconfirm('Are    you sure you want to delete this post?')"%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: You should read and execute the "getting started" rails guide at minimum, it also describes your problem: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-route-for-comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all fix your posts controller. The show action should look like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.includes(:user)   
  end

end
```

Now in app/views/posts/show.html.erb, I would render a partial:

```
<ul>
    <%= render @comments %>
</ul>
```

Rails will look for a partial in app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb. You can just put all your comment view logic in there and will display all the comments:

```
# app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
<li>
  <%= comment.text %>
  <br>
  <%= comment.user.try(:username) %>
</li>
```

Finally, I would fix your create action in the comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # First get the parent post:
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    # Then build the associated model through the parent (this will give it the correct post_id)
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

    # Assign the user directly
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

It seems to me that you don't need to store the username attribute on the comment model, since that should be available through the comment.user association.

Answer (score 0):

in your post#show action simply do:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comments = @post.comments
```

then in your view add:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.text %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```